# Are there any Python modules that decode raw transaction data?

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, raw-data, python

I'm currently doing RPC calls to bitcoin-cli within python to get raw block data:

```
bitcoin-cli getblock BLOCKHASH False
```

I've already written a function that cuts off the block header and splits the transaction block into individual transactions, resulting in the same result as:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawblock TXID
```

I'm now trying to convert this data into the same result as

```
bitcoin-cli getrawblock TXID 1
```

without doing another RPC call to bitcoind. Would prefer to use pre-existing modules if possible.

Python packages would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) (or [this fork](https://github.com/simcity4242/pybitcointools) which has BIP39, file embedding and `mk_opreturn`) can do this.

Install either version of pybitcointools using `setup.py install`, as usual.

Then, with a raw hex transaction, `rawtx`, simply use `txo = deserialize(rawtx)`. `rawtx` can be either a signed or unsigned hex transaction. The returned `txo` is deserialized as a `dict` object. Use `serialize(txo)` to get back to `rawtx`.

You can fetch TxIDs using `fetchtx(hex_txid, source="blockr")` and send signed Txs with `pushtx(signed_hex_tx, source="bci")`.

Comment: Does Pybitcointools send an RPC call to bitcoind to deserialize raw transactions or does it do the conversion within the module?

Comment: @SLee From the module: no RPC required